# Definitive answer regarding retagging homework questions

Tags: discussion, homework

In reading some of the previous questions, I did not have a clear understanding regarding the official SO stance regarding other people adding [homework] to questions which are manifestly homework.  Under what circumstances is it acceptable to retag a question as homework?

Comment: While homework tag itself doesn't bother me, people asking 'is this homework?' on every second post are rather irritating. So, yeah, let's kill it.

Comment: That seems to be an argument in favor of tagging it :)  After all, seeing the homework tag will stymie the flood of "is this homework?" questions

Comment: Isn't the homework tag a meta tag?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I think this question should be tagged as homework like the other homework meta questions.  Rollback if you disagree.

Comment: @Borror0, yeah, it is, but Jeff has stated that it's a... semi-exception... to the rule. That's actually what this question is here to clear up, I think.

Comment: @Popular Demand precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't use [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) unless you're the OP or the OP explicitly states that a question is about homework. [Will's thoughts on this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/70233#70233) are pretty good. In short, he says that the tag adds a lot of noise with little value. I would even say that his policy of not deleting "is this homework" comments doesn't go far enough, because they're often thinly veiled "I'm better than you and your dumb question" comments, and therefore implicitly rude.

So what value does the tag have? As Jeff says, it usually indicates topics covered in CS 101. That's a suboptimal tagging arrangement. I've seen self-learners ask easy but valid questions only to be immediately mobbed by retags and comments. I nearly asked a grad school homework question once, and the only reason I didn't is that I found the answer on another SO post. If we want a tag for CS 101 topics, we should create [cs101](/questions/tagged/cs101) instead of abusing [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).

Comment: Looks like there are in fact three existing `[cs101]` questions.

Comment: How is [cs101] any different from the completely banned [beginner] tag? Logically, they both have the same value/content.  Only [homework] distinguishes beginners from potential cheaters and/or lazy folk.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official stance; reference: ["Is [homework] an exception"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60422/148310) and [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/60495#60495).

I'd say it's acceptable to retag, when -- just like for other tags -- you think that [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) applies.   That is: use your honest judgment.

In my mind, it's often easy to sniff out homework questions.

1. They tend to be vague -- unless you expect a precise meaning to not-always-precise jargon.
   See [this question, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5010474/331508):

   > Given a relation R with n columns. Use sql to returns the tuples having the maximum number of occurrences of the values. I have no idea how to do query horizontally?
2. The questions may have no immediate practical application/details -- they're principle/theory without specifics.
3. They're beginner-level, or show no practical experience.  This is not foolproof, but it's a "tell".
4. They use words like "Given" and/or start sentences with "Use". (^_^)
5. They rarely follow the [guidelines about "Asking about homework"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812) listed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812).

See also, [Etiquette on retagging questions as homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41393/148310) (This question is almost a duplicate of that one).
From [George Stocker's answer to that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41393/etiquette-on-retagging-questions-as-homework/41462#41462):

> The Homework classification has a variety of uses:
>       * Determining which Stack Overflow questions are homework-esque questions
>       * Allowing someone to search homework to see if their particular question has been asked before
>       * Some people use it as a sign that says "Don't do this guy's work for him."